# when bringing in a makehuman model with a rig, the collada (.dae) rig has the regular Octa bones, but they are tiny

Tags: animation, rigging, makehuman, collada, motion-capture

Why are the bones so tiny when I do this and how can I correct it and make them normal size again?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the issue or a more detailed explanation? With what you have in your question it's impossible to say what is going on.

Comment: I have a feeling object is being imported as one scale (ex: centimeters) and bones rig another (Blender units, perhaps)  It might have to do with your export settings.  I've used MakeHuman before, but it's been a while.  Refresh my memory, bones are exported seperately, correct?  While importing COLLADA, on the left,  Import Data Options:  Import Units  When you check this, does it have any effect?

Comment: I think I ran into a similar issue, so I just exported as another filetype, STL if memory serves.

Comment: I use ManuelBastoni Lab nowadays tho, it's better in Blender.  http://www.manuelbastioni.com/guide_main_differences_from_makeHuman.php